# How do I make it mandatory to select at least two options using the React Multiselect component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created one form control using the React Multiselect component. In this control, I want the 'required' to be removed when at least two of the Multiselect fields are selected.Required does not appear when user selects even one. Required appears only when nothing is selected. How can I do that?

[image: q]

[image: q2]

**React JS**

```
const changeSelected = (selectedList, selectedItem) => {
    const values = selectedList.toString();
    setInput({...input, value: values})
    dispatch(saveAnswer('f3', formKey, values))
}



return (
    <>

        <p>{comboboxName}</p>
        <Multiselect className='btn-group'
                     style={{background: "red"}}
                     isObject={false}
                     closeIcon="close"
                     options={options} // Options to display in the dropdown
                     selectedValues={input.value ? input.value.split(',') : []} // Preselected value to persist in dropdown
                     onSelect={changeSelected} // Function will trigger on select event
                     onRemove={changeSelected} // Function will trigger on remove event
                     placeholder=''
        />
        <p></p>
        <Form.Check>
            <Form.Check.Input required
                              checked={input.value != null && input.value.length > 1}
                              style={{display:'none' }}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid" >Required</Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Check>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would solve your problem:

```
 <Form.Check.Input 
     required = {input.value.length < 2}
     checked={input.value.length > 1}
     style={{display:'none' }}
            />
```